# How to get the IsChecked property in the event handler of a checkable menu item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

I am using Caliburn.Micro - and wanted to add a a checkable menuitem. The handler for this action needs to know if the state of the menu item - whether it is checked or not.

XAML:

```
<MenuItem Header="Laser" x:Name="ToggleLaser" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding LaserState}" >
```

ViewModel (Not including code for error recovery):

```
public IEnumerable<IResult> ToggleLaser(bool isChecked)
{
    yield return BusyResult.Show("Turning laser " + (isChecked ? "on" : "off");
    if (isChecked) 
        yield return TurnOnLaserAsync().AsResult();
    else
        yield return TurnOffLaserAsync().AsResult();            
    LaserState = isChecked;
    yield return BusyResult.Hide();
}
```

This did not work - isChecked was allways false.

I *could* get the eventargs:

```
public IEnumerable<IResult> ToggleLaser(RoutedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    var menuItem = (MenuItem)eventArgs.OriginalSource;
    var isChecked = menuItem.IsChecked;
    return ToggleLaser(isChecked);
}
```

But then my viewmodel is bound to my view - not nice.

I could not find a good answer here, so posting this out there as I am sure this is a pretty normal use case for menu items.

Comment: Why you don't user standard binding like `<MenuItem IsChecked={Binding IsChekcedPropertyInViewModel} />`? Something changed in `caliburn`?

Comment: You are correct - standard binding works - my question was unclear - the issue is that ToggleLaser takes time - will update the code in the question

Answer (score 0):

One solution I came up with, is to extend the caliburn framework by adding a new databinding keyword:

```
        MessageBinder.SpecialValues.Add("$ischecked", context =>
        {
            var args = context.EventArgs as RoutedEventArgs;
            if (args == null) {
                return null;
            }
            var fe = args.OriginalSource as MenuItem;
            if (fe == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return fe.IsChecked;
        });
```

And then my XAML becomes:

```
<MenuItem Header="Laser" x:Name="ToggleLaser" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsCheckable="True" cal:Message.Attach="ToggleLaser($ischecked)"/>
```

And my viewmodel becomes

```
public void ToggleLaser(bool turnOn)
    {
        if (turnOn)
            TurnOnLaser();
        else
            TurnOffLaser();
    }
```

Much nicer. :-)

I guess a second option would be to databind the menuitem IsChecked property - this has the benefit of handling cases where something went wrong turning on the laser - but I do not like calling complex functions in a property setter, so I think the better solution is to databind IsChecked *and* use a specific handler.

Comments much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[MenuItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem(v=vs.110).aspx) contains [IsChecked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.ischecked(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

You can simply do the following:

```
<MenuItem Header="Laser"
          x:Name="ToggleLaser" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          IsCheckable="True"
          IsChecked="{Binding IsLaserOn}">
```

And ViewModel:

```
public bool IsLaserOn
{
    get { return this.isLaserOn; }
    set
    {
        if (value == this.isLaserOn)
            return;

        this.isLaserOn = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("IsLaserOn");
        this.ToggleLaser(this.isLaserOn);
    }
}
```

It is simplier rather than create some MessageBinder.

Comment: I agree - it is simpler.
However: My issue was the ToggleLaser takes time - and may fail.
So I want to use the Enumerable<IResult> command for conveying this to the user - I will update the code sample

Comment: You have several options here - you can use TPL explicitly, or you can use IsAsync property when you create the Binding.